# Which creatures count as green creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

This question works with the other colors too, but for now I'm mostly interested in which creatures are valid for benefiting from [Rhonas's Monument](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRhonas%27s%5d%2b%5bMonument%5d):

> Green creature spells you cast cost {1} less to cast.

I can think of two options:

1. All creatures with green in their *color identity*. This means creatures like [Sunder Shaman](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSunder%20Shaman%5d) and [Knight of Autumn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKnight%20of%20Autumn%5d) are cheaper to cast when the monument is in play.
2. All creatures that *only* have green in their color identity. This would exclude multi-colored creatures.

Comment: [Brightsoil Druid](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=413622) has green colour identity, but will not be a green spell when you play it.

Comment: @Arthur please don't answer questions in comments. Comments are meant for getting clarification on questions, not to answer them.

Comment: Be advised that even if Rhona's monument effects applies to the Sunder Chaman, it won't be cheaper to cast. The effect is "cost {1} less" (applying only for numbered mana cost), while Sunder Chaman has only a "colored cost" that can't be reduces this way.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### A creature spell is green if green is one of its colors; it doesn't matter what other colors, if any, it has.

First of all, when an effect asks for the color of an object, it uses the following definition:

> 202.2. An object is the color or colors of the mana symbols in its mana cost, regardless of the color of its frame.

Some cards that would be colorless because of 202.2, such as [Crimson Kobolds](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrimson%20Kobolds%5d) or the back face of most transforming permanents, have a color indicator that sets the card's colors.

> 204.2. An object with a color indicator is each color denoted by that color indicator.

*Color identity* is related to, but different from color. It is only relevant for building Commander decks. A card's color identity is the sum of colors of all mana symbols in that card's mana cost and rules text, plus color indicator:

> 903.4. The Commander variant uses color identity to determine what cards can be in a deck with a certain commander. The color identity of a card is the color or colors of any mana symbols in that card’s mana cost or rules text, plus any colors defined by its characteristic-defining abilities (see rule 604.3) or color indicator (see rule 204).

### With that being said, the answer to your question is option 1, if you replace "color identity" with just "color".

If a card has green among its colors, Rhonas's Monument will identify it as green, regardless of what other colors the card is:

> 202.2c An object with two or more different colored mana symbols in its mana cost is each of the colors of those mana symbols. [..]

If Rhonas's Monument would only apply to mono-green creature spells, it would explicitly say so. Generally speaking, whenever something ask for a property of an object, then it doesn't matter what all other properties of that object are.

For example, you might as well ask whether Rhonas's Monument also applies to "artifact creature" spells such as [Verdurous Gearhulk](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVerdurous%20Gearhulk%5d) instead of just "creature" spells. The answer would also be "yes", because an artifact creature is a creature, and for the Monument it doesn't matter whether or not it's also an artifact.

Also note that your one example of [Sunder Shaman](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSunder%20Shaman%5d) would still not benefit from Rhonas's Monument, because the Monument only reduces *generic* mana costs by 1. Sunder Shaman has no generic mana cost, only colored.

> 117.7a Effects that reduce a cost by an amount of generic mana affect only the generic mana component of that cost. They can’t affect the colored or colorless mana components of that cost.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that the keyword "devoid" can remove a color from a card.

Comment: @Allure That would boil down to "abilities can change the color of objects" and, while true, would not help addressing the question itself or the color/color identity confusion.

Comment: Isn't the real answer "neither of the above", since option 1 involves the _color identity_ and you've just said that only ever matters in Commander?

Comment: @ikegami what do you mean? I did quote 202.2c. 202 was just to clear up what color is vs. color identity.

Comment: Oops, yeah, comment deletewd

Comment: @Allure Devoid is really only an issue for commander and oathbreaker (because it doesn't change color identity), every card that has it also includes full reminder text for it.

Answer (score 8):

[Rhonas's Monument](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRhonas%27s%5d%2b%5bMonument%5d) cares about color not color identity. Color is defined in CR:

> 202.2. An object is the color or colors of the mana symbols in its mana cost, regardless of the color of its frame.

There's also a rule for multicolored cards:

> 202.2c An object with two or more different colored mana symbols in its mana cost is each of the colors of those mana symbols

So in your case both [Sunder Shaman](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSunder%20Shaman%5d) and [Knight of Autumn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKnight%20of%20Autumn%5d) will benefit from Rhona's Monument ability.

To be precise, there is also a rule to determine the color for cards with hybrid and Phyrexian mana:

> 202.2d An object with one or more hybrid mana symbols and/or Phyrexian mana symbols in its mana cost is all of the colors of those mana symbols, in addition to any other colors the object might be.

and for cards with no mana symbols which have a color indicator (like the transformed [Nicol Bolas, the Arisen](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNicol%20Bolas%2c%20the%20Arisen%5d):

> 202.2e An object may have a color indicator printed to the left of the type line. That object is each color denoted by that color indicator.